# Image height after load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I'm having this problem:

```
$('#ajax-div').load(page, function(){ 
    alert(jQuery('#ajax-div img').outerHeight());
});
```

The first time I load the alert says = 0.

If I load again it gets the correct height.

***How can I resolve this first load problem?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the **image is loaded** before you call:

```
$('#ajax-div').load(page, function() {
    jQuery('#ajax-div img').load(function () {
        alert(jQuery(this).outerHeight());
    });
});
```

**More Info:** Look on the Caveats section in [`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/).

Comment: Ok I will try. But I think I already try something like that. And what about If i'm loading more than one image?

Comment: If I don´t know the number of images

Comment: You don't need to know.

Comment: But there are several DOM searches, which is slower than using `this`.